# JQuery: identify duplicate element and remove the old entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've below checkboxes initially:

```
<div class="controls">
  <label class="checkbox" name="Flow">Flow
    <input type="checkbox" value="Flow" name="1" id="8" checked="checked">
  </label>
 <label class="checkbox" name="Timer">Timer
   <input type="checkbox" value="Timer" name="1" id="17" checked="checked">
 </label>
</div>
```

Form my data source I'm appending dynamic checkboxes:

```
data = [{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Respiratory & COPD",
  "slug": "respiratory_and_copd",
  "tests": [{
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Oxygen"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Pressure"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Flow"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Timer"
    }
  ]
}]


$.each(data[0].tests, function(key, val) {
  $('.controls').append('<label class="checkbox" name="' + val.name + '">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="' + val.name + '" id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</label>');
});
```

You can see the `Flow` & `Timer` is also getting created again.

How can I remove the old `flow` & `Timer` and make the new `Flow` & `Timer` checkbox checked?

Old `Flow`& `Timer` have the name attribute and I don't want them.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yck03xhm/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first check if the old checkbox is checked. You can do this in a couple of ways:

```
elem.checked    true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
$( elem ).prop( "checked" )     true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
elem.getAttribute( "checked" )  "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (1.6)   "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (1.6.1+)    "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state
$( elem ).attr( "checked" ) (pre-1.6)   true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```

(from http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

I like the one that gives back the string, so I can insert easily it in the html. After this, you can remove the old checkbox and make a new one.

Btw: your script makes items withe duplicate id's (labels and checkboxes have the same id). This will get you into trouble. It would be safer to change this.

```js
data = [{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Respiratory & COPD",
  "slug": "respiratory_and_copd",
  "tests": [{
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Oxygen"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Pressure"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Flow"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Timer"
    }
  ]
}]


$.each(data[0].tests, function(key, val) {

ischecked=$('#'+val.id).attr( "checked" )
$('#'+val.id).parent().remove()

  $('.controls').append('<label class="checkbox" for="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="' + val.name + '" id="' + val.id + '" '+ischecked+'>' + val.name + '</label>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="controls">
  <label class="checkbox" name="Flow">Flow
    <input type="checkbox" value="Flow" name="1" id="8" checked="checked">
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox" name="Timer">Timer
    <input type="checkbox" value="Timer" name="1" id="17" checked="checked">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It just removed the [name = "1"] elements but don't make the new FLOW and TIMER checked.

Made edit on the post if I didn't explain well sorry

Comment: Actually, I can't use $('[value="Timer"]').prop('checked', true); $('[value="Flow"]').prop('checked', true); This is just some sample code there might be various other values too. I just wanted to know a better way to compare with old value, remove it and keep the new one. This way I guess it won't have an issue with duplicate ID if I remove the old one

Comment: I see. Then it would be good to check if there exists an old checkbox, check if it is checked, remove the old one and make a new one.

Comment: You still need to do something about the fact that label and checkbox are getting the same id in your script. Probably, the label does not need and id at all.

Comment: I'm currently playing around to find an answer. One moment please :-)

Comment: I think the latest edit could give you a useful solution.

Comment: Can you clean up the answer for others :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

For each record you have to add into variable and finally you have to append this to your `.control` element.

Replace your javascript with this:

```
var htmlData = '';
$.each(data[0].tests, function(key, val) {
    htmlData += '<label class="checkbox" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="' + val.name + '" id="' + val.id + '" checked>' + val.name + '</label>'
});
$('.controls').html(htmlData);
```

Try This for your scenario :

```
var htmlData = '';

$.each(data[0].tests, function(key, val) {
var duplicate = $('.controls').find('input[id="'+val.id+'"]');
var isCheck = false;
if(duplicate.length == 1){
    isCheck = "checked";
    }

    htmlData += '<label class="checkbox" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '">' +
      '<input type="checkbox" value="' + val.name + '" id="' + val.id + '" '+isCheck+'>' + val.name + '</label>';
});
$('.controls').html(htmlData);
```

Comment: It makes all the other fields get checked not just FLOW and TIMER

Comment: Please check with the updated code. It works. It will check whether the same checkbox already existed with the id and if exists then it will check it otherwise it will append only.

Comment: Random question why you suggested to use .html() instead of .append()

Comment: Append will not replace the newly updated value in checkboxes, while using html will get you the new value. Suppose id is your primary key in data and name has changed then in that case you have to use .html() instead of .append().